# Add applet to website with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I've never really messed with Java or applets in general, but I want to start learning.  How can I take a simple app I made in eclipse and make it able to be uploaded to a website and to be used in a browser.   I know the question is really generic, but I really have no idea how to do this, so any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets are simply Java programs included in an HTML page.
The HTML page contains info to inform the browser which applet to load and where to place it inside a web page.
E.g.

```
In `applet.html`
<applet code="SomApplet.class" width="300" height="300">
</applet>
```

A java application (specifically a Swing application) can be turned into an applet.
You have to extend `JApplet` and implement `init`.
So broadly speaking, modify your swing application you created in Eclipse to extend a JApplet, and create the required code tags.
For more help you should post your application code

Comment: How can I do it if there is more then one class file?

Comment: Just create a jar of your classes. Declare the main class of the applet as `CODE` and refer the jar from `ARCHIVE`